# field with null=True not accepting nulls in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing some models. Specifically, a UserProfile model which is created by a post save hook on User.

Some strange things are happening here. The test suite passes on one computer, and fails on another. The error message is : `profile_userprofile.organization_id may not be NULL`, and yet here is my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    'Profile object for a user'
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        'organization.Organization',
        related_name='volunteers',
        null=True,
    )
```

obviously, organization should allow null values, but it doesn't. Any ideas as to what's going wrong here? The same thing happens when calling `User.objects.create()` from the shell.

(oh, here's the hook)

```
@receiver(models.signals.post_save, sender=User)
def user_post_save(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    'create a userprofile object for a user if one does not exist'
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
```

Comment: Did you sync your db after changing `null` to `True`?

Comment: Yes, and the test suite creates and drops an in-memory database every time.

Comment: What kind of db are you using (when running the test suite)?

Comment: Try making it `blank=True, null=True`.

Comment: @lazerscience: SQLite, Postgre in production
@John C: done. Still exists.

It seems to be ignoring the option no matter where I put it in the call, which is sort of to be expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing a migration! Whoops!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the database is not on sync in the second machine. Drop it and re-run `syncdb`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are looking for is [`blank=True`](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/28/django-tips-difference-between-blank-and-null/).

Comment: Nope, see comments on the question. Doesn't fix it.

Comment: Or do you mean using solely `blank=True`?